# Flutter shape overlapping screen width

Tags: flutter, dart, shapes, overlap

How can I make a shape (or any *widget* for that matter) overlap the sides of the phone-screen?

---

I've attached an image that showes what I mean.

Here's my code so far:

```
Container(
                  width: 900.0,
                  height: 900.0,
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.orange,
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  ),
                ),
```

---

> And no, I it doesn't help to increse the size to say 1000, it just stays the same

---

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just modified the answer.

```
Transform.scale(
      scale: 1.4,
      child: Center(
        child: Container(
          width: 900.0,
          height: 900.0,
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.orange,
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a `Transform` widget with a proper `scale` property and remove the `height` and `width` in the `Container`.

```
Transform.scale(
  scale: 1.7,
  child: Container(
    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.orange,
      shape: BoxShape.circle,
    ),
  ),
)
```